# Access to UI from Dependency Service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to use StepCounter in my Xamarin.Forms project.
If I have correctly understood, I need to use Dependency Service, write the interface for stepcounter and his realisation on Android/IOS app.

The problem is that I'd like to update ui control (text) every moment, when stepper sensor state changed. For example in Android we have

```
using Android.Hardware;
/*Dependency Service header 
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(.....
*/
...
namespace tmp
{
 public class Stepper : ISensorEventListener, INameOfDependencyInterface
 {
   public static void Init()
    {
    SensorManager senMgr = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);
         Sensor counter = senMgr.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepCounter);

         if (counter != null)
         {
             senMgr.RegisterListener(this, counter, SensorDelay.Normal);
         }
    }
  public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        /*something that change text on ui*/
    }
 }
}
```

Here, as you can see, I would like to change text in UI in OnSensorChanged void.

Maybe this problem have better solution, such as something like that:

1. Make call form platform dependency service class realisation to PCL or make something like listener in PCL
2. In PCL make timer, that do response to dependency service and getting stepcounter value, for example, every second
3. To forget Xamarin.Forms and migrate to Xamarin.Native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an `Action` to your `Init` constructor, and it will called when sensor changed:

```
public class Stepper : ISensorEventListener, INameOfDependencyInterface
{

    private Action<float> _stepCountChanged;

    public static void Init(Action<float> stepCountChanged)
    {
        SensorManager senMgr = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);
        Sensor counter = senMgr.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepCounter);

        if (counter != null)
        {
            senMgr.RegisterListener(this, counter, SensorDelay.Normal);
        }

        _stepCountChanged = stepCountChanged;
    }
    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        _stepCountChanged(e.Values.First());

    }
}
```

Init it like this in you `Activity` for example:

```
DependencyService.Get<...>().Init((steps) => { 
    // Label.Steps = steps;
});
```